# How to check file is updated after secret updated in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I create a secret and mount it as file in pod(config in deployment).
If I change the secret, the mounted file will be changed in few seconds.
But how can I check the file is updated actually? I don't want to exec into pod and check it , because I want to check it by k8s api or k8s resource status. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: If I don't misunderstand, what you would like to do is to know when the mounted file is refreshed exactly. The activity refresh is executed by `kubelet` on each node in less than 1 minute by default. You may check them on each node at the secret mount point via `inotify`. It is easier to do the same thing in Pods. Why would you like to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't really in general check that Kubernetes is not broken. Unless you think you've found a bug, in which case you would use `kubectl exec` and probably many other things to try and track it down.